# base 10 to base 2 sum of digits

Tags: number-theory

A number $t$ base $10$ has the same sum of digits base $10$ and base $2$. What is the largest possible value of $t<1000$.

I tried making an equation using remainders conversion method thing but I'm stuck.

Comment: How many digits can a base $2$ number less than $1000$ have? This gives an upper bound to the sum of digits, thus narrowing down your search.

Comment: Between this and your recent questions, it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.

Comment: I'm not. If I wanted other people to solve my homework I could just use wolframalpha or other sites like that.